# Is it possible to filter the class display in Protegé?

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I am designing a new ontology, which references the (very large!) Ontology of Units of Measure (om-2): http://www.ontology-of-units-of-measure.org/page/om-2

This makes it hard to work with Protegé because it seems that I am left with one of two bad alternatives:

1. The small number of classes in my ontology are swamped in the display by om-2 classes (displaying with prefix helps, but only a little).
2. I don't include om-2 in the Protegé project and just refer to classes from there. As far as I can tell, this hampers Protegé's ability to work with a DL reasoner.

Is there some way to tell Protegé to filter the display and hide the om-2 classes?  Being able to toggle this would be a huge help.

Comment: isn't `View -> Show only the active ontology` what you're asking for?

Comment: @UninformedUser Yes, that's what I needed to know. Would you promote this to an answer, and I will give you credit for answering?